# String formatting in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, string.format

Numerical values were inserted to `JTextArea` and by saveButton I am saving these values to text file.

For example, sample of data with 4 column (rows and columns not constant):

```
10  0.11E+10  0.15E+10 10
123 0.12E+10  0.16E+10 20
345 0.13E+10  0.17E+10 30
```

So now I want to divide each column in these style (80 column punched card format):

```
1---------12---------23---------34
10        0.11E+10   0.15E+10   10
123       0.12E+10   0.16E+10   20
345       0.13E+10   0.17E+10   30
```

I found that `String.format` can be used, for example:

```
String tf = jTextField.getText();
System.out.println(String.format("%11d", tf));
```

I would like to ask can I implement `String.format` to divide numerical data columns?

Comment: Use a JTable...you'll need to split the String into individual columns/elements

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have to use `JTextArea`, is it impossible to split using `JTextArea`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right, but you could try `Font.MONOSPACED` on the `JTextArea`.

Comment: Nope, you'll have to pre-split the String regardless of what solution you use